Is "to the degree that" an idiom in this context?

"Sentenced to death" is a figure of speech to the degree that no court literally pronounced a death sentence on him, but the effect is still "decreed that he was to die."

Source: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/english-deserved-sentenced-him-to-death-education-magoo-to-stay-u-s-asylum-granted.4105499/post-21097779
It would seem to me that, given the context, "to degree that" means "in the sense that" and therefore that it doesn't have the literal meaning.
Is "to the degree that" an idiom in this case?

It's fine but this is asking for editing.

But isn't it the case that courts can sentence criminals to death, literally?
"To the degree that" would fit this definition:

degree: "The amount that an entity possesses a certain property; relative intensity, extent."  (from wiktionary)

"To the extent that" is being applied to "figure of speech". What it's saying is that the phrase "sentenced to death" isn't fully a figure of speech, but it's somewhat being used that way.  The expression is idiomatic to the extent that the man wasn't literally sentenced to death, but effectively received a death sentence.
You are correct that it means "in the sense that". However, "to the degree that" doesn't seem wrong. The description partly applies and partly doesn't.  Thus, "to an extent".
